# Regex to get a specific part of an URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

Say I've got an URL:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar/yes_no_no.html
```

I'm looking for a regex that can extract all the characters of the filename up to the first underscore. So in the above URL I want to extract "yes".

So far I managed to get the whole "yes_no_no" bit using:

`/([^\/]+)(?=\.\w+$)/`, but I can't seem to get it to only match "yes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\/([^_\/]+)_?[^\/]*\.[a-z]+$/
```

Example:

```js
console.log('http://www.example.com/foo/bar/yes_no_no.html'.match(/\/([^_\/]+)_?[^\/]*\.[a-z]+$/)[1])
console.log('http://www.example.com/foo/bar/yes.html'.match(/\/([^_\/]+)_?[^\/]*\.[a-z]+$/)[1])
```